# Rails 5 api - undefined method `user_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I started a new project with Rails 5 in API mode.

For the moment i just create the project, set the database and use the scaffold command.

```
rails g scaffold User
```

I try my code with postman to create a new user (POST)

Request

```
URI localhost:3000/v1/users
{
    "first_name": "Firstname",
    "last_name": "Lastname",
    "email": "anemail@gmail.com32"
}
```

Result

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `user_url' for #<Api::V1::UsersController:0x005594d8a4ad90>
```

How can i fix that error ?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: 'api' do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, :as => 'user'
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
# POST /users
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if @user.save
    render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
  else
    render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: Check your routes with bin/rails routes.. I think you need to write v1_user_url

Comment: I think "location:" call a bad url. Am i right ?

Comment: Correct. Remove that.

Comment: You also need to make sure your User model has the 3 fields you want in it.

Answer (score 9):

Try to change `location: @user` to `location: v1_user_url(@user)`

Comment: Alternative: `url_for([:v1, @user])` ...

Got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46873712

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing your namespace and scope:

```
namespace :api, path: '/'  do
  scope module: :v1 do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

Comment: I have the error "routing/mapper.rb:859:in `scope': no block given (yield)"

Comment: Forgot a 'do' above. Try again.